# Shadow around transparent Rect in Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas, paint

I just want the shadow of an empty box. But if I give the `Rect` a transparent `Paint` color the shadow becomes transparent too. Is this possible?

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
//paint.setColor(0x00000000);
paint.setShadowLayer(10, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);

Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a second `Canvas` and a second `Bitmap` and then merge them after I cut out some parts with `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`. This way I create layers like in image editing applications and don't lose the background.

This is how I cut parts out:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

And this is how I put the layers back together:

```
bottomCanvas.drawBitmap(topBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```